# how to solve bad request in django rest-frame-workd

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework

I have created an api which accepts user email and password to login. When ever i tried accessing the api, i get bad request. I have been searching the need, looking at my code. but yet i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. Please help

Below my html form

```
 <form id="loginform"action="userlogin/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="errors-field">
 </div>
 <div class="input-field">
 <label >
 Email
 </label>
 <input placeholder="Email"type="email" name="email" value=""required>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field">
 <label>
 Password
</label>
<input placeholder="Password"type="password" name="password" value=""required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

My java script below

```
const lgform  = document.querySelector('#loginform')
lgform.addEventListener('submit',loginForm)
function loginForm(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const myform      = event.target
    const myFormData  = new FormData(myform)
    const url         = myform.getAttribute("action")
    const method      = myform.getAttribute("method")
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
    const xhr         = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(method,url)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUEST_WITH","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-with","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",csrftoken)
    xhr.onload=function(){
    const serverResponse = xhr.response
    const serverData     = JSON.parse(serverResponse)
    console.log(serverData.email)
    if(xhr.status==200){
    if(serverData.token){
        cname  = "user" 
        cvalue = serverData.token
        exdays = 1
        setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
        }
    }

}
xhr.onerror=function(){
  console.log('error')
}

xhr.send(myFormData)
```

}

my serilialozer

```
class loginUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'},write_only=True,required=True)
    email    = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    def validate_email(self,value):
    
        data = self.get_initial()
        pw   = data.get('password')
        email= value 
        user=authenticate(email=email,password=pw)
        if not user or not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('email or password not correct')
        
       return value
```

My api view

```
class loginUser(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data ={}
        serializer  = loginUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            email    = serializer.validated_data['email']
            password = serializer.validated_data['password']
            user     = authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                try:
                    usertoken = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                    data ={'token':usertoken.key}
                   print(usertoken)
              except:
                pass
             else:
                 data =serializer.errors
        return Response(data,status=200)
```

I get  api bad request when form is submitted. Please i need to figure out what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

In my console log, when i print out the server response data,you can see below

```
Object { detail: "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }
```

Comment: check the ***response*** of the API request. It should contain the relevant info regarding the bad request.

Comment: Well, as you can see in my code, what i my missing out ?

Answer (score -1):

I was not suppose to include

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")

in my header